# Getting Sharepoint to calculate columns and render them as a | delimited

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, calculated-column-formula

This a great online community! I am trying to get columns to calculate and then display the calculated value in delimited format.

Example is `[COLUMN 1]+[COLUMN 2]+[COLUMN 3]`

The calculated result I would like to see for importation reasons will be

```
COLUMN1|COLUMN2|COLUMN3
```

Any thoughts on this are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the number of columns is fixed:

```
=[COLUMN 1] & "|" & [COLUMN 2] & "|" & [COLUMN 3]
```